# How to get audio to float right in css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get all three of my audios to float right via css. Not sure what I'm missing or messing up.

In css I have tried changing the 'audio' to .audio and #audio , also tried changing it to music since that is what my div is called. None of that worked.

```css
audio
{
    align:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="Music" style="width:650px; background-color: #dcdcdc; border: #00008b 2px dashed;" > 

    <h1>My Favorite Music</h1>

    <p>Jrad</p>
    <audio controls style= "display:block">
    <source type="audio/ogg"
    src="media/jrad2019-07-13.cmc621.cmc64.sbd.matrix-t03.ogg">
    </audio>

    <p>Swagger by Joe Russo's Almost Dead</p>
    <audio controls style= "display:block">
    <source type="audio/mp3"
    src="media/jrad2019-01-19.cmc621.cmc65xt.sbd.matrix-s1t01.mp3">
    </audio>

    <p>Marco Solo by Joe Russo's Almsot Dead</p>   
    <audio controls style= "display:block">
    <source type="audio/mp3"
    src="media/jrad2019-03-16.cmc621.cmc64.sbd.matrix-s1t04.mp3">
    </audio>

    <p>Jam by Joe Russo's Almost Dead</p> 
    <audio controls style= "display:block">
    <source type="audio/mp3"
    src="media/jrad2019-04-27.cmc621.cmc64.sbd.matrix-s1t01.mp3">
    </audio>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex;` to get a 1x1 layout and then apply `flex-grow: 1;` to `p` to set the element to maximum available width.

```css
#Music {
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
  border: #00008b 2px dashed;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper p {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="Music">

  <h1>My Favorite Music</h1>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Jrad</p>
    <audio controls style="display:block">
    <source type="audio/ogg"
    src="media/jrad2019-07-13.cmc621.cmc64.sbd.matrix-t03.ogg">
    </audio>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

always use wrappers so you can control it and use display flex it will align

```css
.wrap{display:flex;
justify-content:space-between;}
```

```html
<div id="Music" style="width:650px; background-color: #dcdcdc; border: #00008b 2px dashed;" > 

    <h1>My Favorite Music</h1>

   <div class=wrap> <p>Jrad</p>
    <audio controls style= "display:block">
    <source type="audio/ogg"
    src="media/jrad2019-07-13.cmc621.cmc64.sbd.matrix-t03.ogg">
    </audio></div>

   <div class=wrap>  <p>Swagger by Joe Russo's Almost Dead</p>
    <audio controls style= "display:block">
    <source type="audio/mp3"
    src="media/jrad2019-01-19.cmc621.cmc65xt.sbd.matrix-s1t01.mp3">
    </audio></div>
 <div class=wrap>
    <p>Marco Solo by Joe Russo's Almsot Dead</p>   
    <audio controls style= "display:block">
    <source type="audio/mp3"
    src="media/jrad2019-03-16.cmc621.cmc64.sbd.matrix-s1t04.mp3">
    </audio></div>
 <div class=wrap>
    <p>Jam by Joe Russo's Almost Dead</p> 
    <audio controls style= "display:block">
    <source type="audio/mp3"
    src="media/jrad2019-04-27.cmc621.cmc64.sbd.matrix-s1t01.mp3">
    </audio></div></div>
```